# Primefaces Paginator

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple primefaces datatable with paginator="true".  The table has data and the arrow buttons are showing for the paginator but when I click one nothing happens.  It doesn't even appear to post back to the server.  Here is my datatable declaration:

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" var="currentRow" value="#{myBean.Items}" paginator="true" rows="10">
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you're initializing the list data in the constructor or in the `@PostConstruct` method of your managed beanand the getter just returns the `List<Item>` attribute value. Also, for ajax requests, it will be better to have your managed bean configured to `@ViewScoped` at least.

Comment: Please post your managedBean here.

Comment: Try to follow the PF showcase example as a proof of concept.  Also, what type of list is **Items**? Usually if its a list of class (not String), you will have to initialise the var property of the datatable tag in order to access it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your table is inside a `<h:form>` element.